# How to user controlled overlap images in JS

Tags: javascript, overlapping

I'm desperately searching for solution for my client. I have graphic - something like that:

[image: slider]

And I want to be able to take the line with circle in the center and drag it to right or left. And it will be hiding and unhiding my two full images. It's basically two images on the same place, just with another z-index I think.

I think it's possible to do it with JavaScript, but I don't know of any functions or methods for this option.

Comment: Probably done with a jQuery slider, but not sure exactly what will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

The HTML is pretty simple, just two divs for the images and one for the drag:

```
<div class="img" id="img1"></div>
<div class="img" id="img2"></div>
<div id="drag"></div>
```

For the CSS, the important part is to absolute position all the divs and give a background image.

As for the Javascript, with a little help from jQuery, we listen for the mouse events, make some calculations and adjust the CSS of the second image:

```
$('#drag').on('mousedown', function(e){
    var $self = $(this),
        dragPos = $self.position().left + $self.width()/2,
        imgWidth = $('#img1').width();

    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
        $(document).off('mouseup').off('mousemove');
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(me){
        var mx = me.pageX - e.pageX + dragPos
        $self.css({ left: mx });

        $('#img2').css({
          width: imgWidth - mx,
          left: mx,
          backgroundPosition: -mx + 'px 0px',
        });
    });
});
```

From there, I believe it's pretty easy to customize it and give it a unique look.
Hope this helps!

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pGGUm/)

Comment: So you're essentially setting the width of the left image's div to end at the divider, and setting the background of the right image to always be lined up on the left edge of the left image, is that right? Works really well, nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this alphamask plugin](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/alphamask) may do the trick, though I'm not sure how simple it would be for you to implement in the manner of your slider example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not seems to be what I'm looking for. There are filtering stuffs with blur and I want to 100% hiding and unhiding.

Comment: @JohnCz. I understand the example on that page isn't exactly what you're looking for. I'm saying the base functionality is at the heart of what you're trying to do: use one image to mask another, and allow the user to control that mask. You have to actually put in some work to customize a library like the one I linked to make it fit your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually quite simple. The first step is to make it work manually. I'd set it up as follows:

```
<div class="wrap" id="wrap1">
  <div class="img-wrap img1"></div>
  <div class="img-wrap img2"></div>
<div>
```

With CSS as follows:

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.img1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(bg1.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.img2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background: url(bg1.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

Now some JavaScript (with jQuery) to set a position (you can call this when you move a slider over the top later):

```
function setPosition(percentage){
  // get the width of the container
  var w = $('#wrap1').width();
  // work out the width of left panel
  var w1 = Math.floor(w * percentage);
  // and the right panel
  var w2 = w - w1;
  // set the width of the right panel
  // move it right by the width of the left panel
  // and move the background back by the width of the left panel
  $('#wrap1 .img2').css({
    width: w2,
    left: w1,
    backgroundPosition: -w1 + 'px 0px',
  });
}
```

You now just have to decide how to do the dragging. You could even just do it on mouseOver. Easy!